# Duda con formulario HTML y Flask con varios botones submit

Tags: html, python, css, flask, python-requests

Estoy empezando con el framework de Flask, ando haciendo una app para descargar videos de YouTube, pero tengo la duda en que tengo dos botones uno para descargar los video en alta calidad y otra para baja calidad, tengo en Python la función para bajarlos en alta calidad y el botón funciona con esta, pero para hacer la del segundo botón no eh podido ya que no se como hacer para que al darle al botón me llame a la función de bajar a baja calidad (aun no lo programo pero porque es que no se como hacer en HTML que al darle al botón vaya a esa función).
Adjunto códigos:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Youtube Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Descargador de Videos de Youtube</h1>
 <form method="POST">
    <label for="link">Enlace Youtube</label>
    <input type="url" id="link" name="link" placeholder="Link Youtube">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Descargar video alta resolución</button>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Descargar video baja resolución</button>
    <br>
    <button type="reset">Borrar campos</button>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-download" href="{{ archivo3 }}" download="">Descargar</a>
 </form>
 <br>
  <div class="alert">
      <h3>{{ message }}</h3>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Python:

```
@appyoutube.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Descarga():
  if request.method== "POST":
    enlace=request.form["link"]
    if enlace!="":
        video= YouTube(enlace)
        video= video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        archivo=video.download(descarga_carpeta)
        mensaje= "Video Descargado"
        archivo1=archivo.split("\D")[-1]
        archivo2="D"+archivo1
        return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje, archivo3=archivo2)
    else:
        mensaje= "El campo esta vacio"
        return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje)
  else:
      return render_template("Youtube.html")
```

Comment: deberías crear una ruta para cada tipo de descarga, al presionar el boton solo realizas una petición con js y se realiza la descaraga. Puedes ver [mi  repo](https://github.com/nakato156/downmusic) donde hice una app para descaragar música

Comment: Hola Cristian si como puedes ver tengo una carpeta para las descargas, pero el problema esta en que quiero que en el formulario HTML al darle al botón de baja calidad se llame la función o vaya a la condición para hacer eso, porque solo seria cambiar el ".get_highest_resolution()" por ".get_low_resolution()" pero no eh podido hacer que en el HTML los botones funcionen distinto ya que ambo van a lo mismo, no se si me hago entender, aun así mirare tu sugerencia

Comment: nop, creo que no entendiste, no hablo de la carpeta, hablo de crear rutas para cada acción específica y  solicitarlas mediante una petición con JS

Comment: Hola Christian bueno no se de JS entonces no sabría como hacer eso, pero entonces si se podría enlazar con los botones?

Comment: [Yo diría que...](https://omnipc.ddns.net/yodiriaque.html?answer=sip)

Answer (score -2):

Ya logre encontrar una solución usando radiobuttons :D

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
<title>Youtube Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Descargador de Videos de Youtube</h1>
 <form method="POST">
    <label for="link">Enlace Youtube</label>
    <input type="url" id="link" name="link" placeholder="Link 
 Youtube">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="alta">Alta 
   Resolución
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="baja">Baja 
  Resolución
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="audio">Solo 
  Audio
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="720p">720p
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="480p">480p
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="240p">240p
    <input type="radio" id="res" name="res" value="144p">144p
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Descargar</button>
    <br>
    <button type="reset">Borrar campos</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a class="fcc-btn" href="{{ archivo3 }}" 
 download="">Descargar</a>
</form>
<br>
<div class="alert">
    <h3>{{ message }}</h3>
</div>
```

Python:

```
@appyoutube.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Descarga():
 if request.method== "POST":
    enlace=request.form["link"]
    if enlace!="":
        video= YouTube(enlace)
        calidad=request.form["res"]
        if calidad=="audio":
            video=video.streams.get_audio_only()
            mensaje="Audio Descargado"
            archivo=video.download(descarga_carpeta)
            archivo1=archivo.split("\D")[-1]
            archivo2="D"+archivo1
            return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje, 
 archivo3=archivo2)
        elif calidad=="alta":
            video= video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            mensaje= "Video Descargado"
            archivo=video.download(descarga_carpeta)
            archivo1=archivo.split("\D")[-1]
            archivo2="D"+archivo1
            return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje, 
 archivo3=archivo2)
        elif calidad=="baja":
            video= video.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
            mensaje= "Video Descargado"
            archivo=video.download(descarga_carpeta)
            archivo1=archivo.split("\D")[-1]
            archivo2="D"+archivo1
            return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje, 
  archivo3=archivo2)
        else:
            video= video.streams.get_by_resolution(calidad)
            mensaje= "Video Descargado"
            archivo=video.download(descarga_carpeta)
            archivo1=archivo.split("\D")[-1]
            archivo2="D"+archivo1
            return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje, 
 archivo3=archivo2)
    else:
        mensaje= "El campo esta vacio"
        return render_template("Youtube.html", message=mensaje)
else:
    return render_template("Youtube.html")
```

Comment: podrías colocar el código? por favor lee [answer]